# Glitch reduction

Tags: digital-logic

What are the techniques that are used in Industry to prevent combinational logic glitches?

If there is any glitch in data in combinational circuit how it can be removed?

Comment: You need to ask a more specific question.  Your question is so broad that any reasonable answer would be too long for this site.  This site isn't suited to *Tell me all about xxx"*.

Comment: D types play a role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Combinatorial glitches are a matter of Nature. Signal combinations race over different signal paths and anything can happen during transitional stage. The Industry solution is to use synchronizing latches, and register the combinatorial state only when all transitions settle down. It is done on periodical basis called "clock". Because of the transients need some propagation time to settle, the clock has limitation on upper side. That's why CPUs (and all other circuits) are clock-limited.

There are also some design technique called "self-clocking" circuits, or "domino logic". Some elements were used in some Pentium processors. Unfortunately the self-clocking circuits are almost impossible to debug, and now it is a matter of academic curiosity.

Comment: If we use synchronizing latches it will increase the latency.Isn't it?

Comment: @new_ecl, which latency? Yes, the throughput of device is fixed by the clock cycle, and there are always some intermediate pipeline stages that work faster than the clock, so the trade-off is "digital accuracy" versus unpredictable glitchy and flaky never-working circuit.